# Is there any way to get whatsapp profile pic?? ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, whatsapp

Can i get the whatsapp profile pictures. Is there any chance. Is whatsapp given that feature ?? Is there any integration or any code please provide me
Suggest me pls.

Thanks

Comment: Actually i need from whatsapp only. That will use for me

Comment: Is there any way to get it??

Comment: I have no idea. Stackoverflow is not a site to do your research for you. Its for answering questions about code and errors. Google whats app api or sdk. If theres nothing there then its probably not possible. Its a fairly unusual request to begin with

Answer (score 3):

WhatsApp does not provide any API or SDK for developers.
Still you can look into this GitHub project for some reference.

https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI

You can also look into this discussion group.

http://www.quora.com/Does-WhatsApp-have-an-API

But mostly the answer to your question is NO. I am not sure if there is a little hack to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks Apple_iOS0304,  Helpful to me